# Returning an instance of a generic class from a method (C#)

Tags: c#, generics

Class A is generic: `A<T>`. Another class `B` has a method "getA" that should return an instance of A. Is it possible to define this method as "`A getA()`", without specifying the type of the A instance returned in the signature?

If it's not possible, is the only solution to also define B as `B<T>` and then define the method as "`A<T> getA()`"? It feels somewhat cumbersome, as B itself is not necessarily of generic type.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you going to use instance returned by `getA` if you will not know type of generic parameter?

Comment: You have to provide the type of the generic parameter. If you don't know that type at compile time, either you make the method generic or the class generic (`B` in this case), but always have to provide it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make some interface to operate with A and return it

```
public class A<T> : IAOperationInterface
{
}

public class B
{
    public IAOperationInterface getA()
    {
         return //... some build code.....
    }
}
```

or...

```
public class B<T>
{
    public IAOperationInterface getA()
    {
         return new A<T>()
    }
}
```

Comment: But in the body of `getA` remains the problem, right?

Comment: in the body we have to make some instance, with builder passed some how or something else.

Answer (score -1):

You can define generic method in non generic class B:

```
class B
{
    public A<T> GetA<T>()
    {
        return new A<T>();
    }
}
```

But it is not clear from question whether it is what you want.